# Larawel orWhere query from concat two column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a users table:
id | firstname | lastname
when displaying users data, I have a filter name so a user can search by name (first, last or full name);
the problem is when I input it fullname it result in 0 data,
eg:
fistname: michael
lastname: foobar
when i look for "michael" and "foobar" i have no problem, but when i look for "michael foobar" it return nothing

my code look like this:

```
$dataQuery  = $dataQuery->where(function ($dataQuery) use ($fullname) {
            $dataQuery->where('users.firstname', 'like', '%' . $fullname . '%')
                  ->orWhere('users.lastname', 'like', '%' . $fullname . '%')
                  ->orWhere('CONCAT_WS(" ", `users.firstname`, `users.lastname`)', 'LIKE', '%' . $fullname . '%');
        });
```

ps: I'm sorry for my lack of english, i hope y'all understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using mysql in-built function `CONCAT_WS`, plz use `DB::raw()` for the function:

```php
->orWhere(DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", `users.firstname`, `users.lastname`)'), 'LIKE', '%' . $fullname . '%');
```